# How is the effect for refreshing sandboxes once we enable SSO in production?

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-authentication

I have deployed a domain in the production and configured SSO on it. I need to know, how is the url of refreshing sandboxes and can we configure SSO both sandboxes and production parallel?

Comment: If the URL on production is like https://abcd.my.salesforce.com/, the URL on sandbox will have the sandbox name appended with 2 hyphens and will also have the sandbox instance name added. E.g. https://abcd--sbuat.cs9.my.salesforce.com/ . At lease this is how our instances get the URL after the refresh. You can enable SSO on the sandbox in parallel as well provided you have a different configuration / environment available on the Identity Provider side as well for the sandbox.

Comment: Useful link on this. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175165&language=en_US